# How to setup a Composable text field to autofill address with keyboard?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, autofill, composable

I would like to setup a composable input text field, which when on focused, it will show the suggested address on the keyboard similar to how the keyboard is able to show suggested payment card info. I have already enabled autofill on my phone, but don't know how to set-up the text field in code.

[image: example of how the keyboard suggests a payment info]

Answer (score 0):

It is not yet supported the way its supported in xml with autofillHints.

If you want autofill on your composable, you'll have to program it manually by extension functions on the Modifier.

```
fun Modifier.autofill(/*...*/){
    /*...*/
}
```

Here is the docs for the autofill node
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/autofill/package-summary